# How to calculate duty cycle of a servo motor?

Tags: motor, frequency, motor-controller, servo, duty-cycle

I have this [servo motor](https://www.blue-bird-model.com/products_detail/125.htm) and in its specifications only speed and torque is given:

```
Torque At 4.8V  3.5 kg-cm / 49 oz-in
Torque At 6.0V  4.4 kg-cm / 61 oz-in
Speed At 4.8V   0.25 sec / 60°
Speed At 6.0V   0.22 sec / 60°
```

How to determine frequency and duty cycle of this motor? I am connecting this motor to 5V pin of a microcontroller.

Comment: These two answers for Rpi might help: (1) Run the program in the laptop and use the raspberry gpios, PWM to control servo
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99315/run-the-program-in-the-laptop-and-use-the-raspberry-gpios-pwm-to-control-servos/99316#99316

(2) How to use Rpi python GPIO pins in PWM output mode to create PWM signals?
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120452/how-to-use-rpi-python-gpio-pins-in-pwm-output-mode-to-create-pwm-signals/120453#120453

Comment: And a video demo: Swing servo 2019may1201
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmKMAUFQ668

Answer (score 1):

```
Speed At 4.8V   0.25 sec / 60°
Speed At 6.0V   0.22 sec / 60°
```

At 4.8V if it takes 0.25sec for a 60 degrees shift then for a full shift (360 degrees) we will need 6*0.25 = 1.5s which is the period of the shift.

f = 1/T = 1/1.25 = 0.8Hz

The same way for 6.0V

We don't have enough info for the duty cycle of the motor.

Comment: Does you calculation mean that it can hold its angular position for more than 1 second without giving any further pulses?